# Customize Firefox background color of the browser between page load

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to customize the background color of the browser canvas to black as per instructions from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1006290#answer-647667) but it doesn't seem to work for me, I'm using **ChromEdit** to edit the css config.

I would like to change it to black instead of white.

**UserChrome.css**:

```
browser { background-color: #000 !important; }
```

Anyone every tried to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is more suitable for superuser.com but since you already got a reply I'll give in.

If my memory serves well `about:blank` used to be a chrome page. Now it a content page, though one with special treatment. But for the purpose of tweaking its css we can consider it no different than `example.com`

So edit `userContent.css` with the following code

```css
@-moz-document url("about:blank") {
  body {
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(
      to right, 
      red, 
      orange, 
      yellow
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be that you are using the file name `UserChrome.css`.  The file should be `userChrome.css`. Note the lowercase "u". When using `userChrome.css` the code:

```
browser { background-color: #000 !important; }
```

works for me.

However, under normal conditions, this is only displayed for a *very* brief amount of time.  In some configurations, it may not be visible.

Comment: hey there, I did write UserChrome here but my actualy css does look like the way you typed it, I'm also following up with the folks on the Mozilla forum and it seems like that this used to work good but doesn't anymore, now it either doesn't work or it's barely noticeable. I'll keep looking for a hack, thanks!

Comment: @paul-2011: The `browser` background is only displayed for *very* brief periods. I am not surprised that you see little or no difference. I have to work at making it appear, and it only does so the first time I transition through that display, but it is shown. This question is limited to how to get the browser CSS statement to work, which does not solve what you actually want even when working. A separate question that makes it clear as to what you are actually attempting to accomplish might be helpful. It could be: I want to do X. I tried `browser ...` which did not work. How can I do X?